# Python understanding list comprehension from Java background

Tags: python

I come from a Java background and **just started to work on Python**. Most of the things are fairly easy to pick up but I am having hard time to understand one thing in the language which I just found out that is called list comprehension. What is this **list comprehension in Python**? How does this compare with language constructs found in Java? The problem is it's everywhere, nearly all the examples I found here and there use it.

For the following example, allow me to understand how this works.

```
[x**2 for x in range(10)]
```

And then there this.

```
[j + k for j in 'abc' for k in 'def']
```

Beyond that I also have seen things like this somewhere on Stackoverflow.

```
(x for x in (0,1,2,3,4))
```

Also things like this.

```
total = sum(x+y for x in (0,1,2,3) for y in (0,1,2,3) if x < y)
```

This started to get messy, could you please help me?

Comment: Have you tried to run these in your python shell? List comprehension are a way to generate lists.

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? When you have this type of expression within `[]` it is a "list comprehension", within `{}` is a "dict comprehension" and within `()` is a "generator expression", but all of them work similarly, it's just that the type at the end differs.

Comment: There's 2 parts to this, some rule to generate a sequence and a data type to store that generated sequence in. First you must have a rule to generate a sequence of values, for example `x**2 for x in range(10)` iterates over `range(10)` by setting `x` to each value in that sequence and then generates the sequence of `x**2` for each value. Because this is of the form `[sequence]` you get a list. If it were `{sequence}` you would get a set, of if it was `(sequence)` you would get a generator expression.

Comment: yes I have tried these and trying to understand the difference, as there are lots of it and I get confused in each of them :(

Comment: It might be easy for you to say if you are not starting a new language but I already checked other answers. I truly want to understand this :(

Comment: Although these questions are closely related, I am not sure that this is a duplicate.

Comment: This is a bit annoying, I wrote a long answer explaining how this works from a Java perspective but it got closed before I could post. Python and Java have a very different approach to this type of problem.

Comment: Can't agree more. We should be more welcoming otherwise #SOreadytohelp tag wouldn't mean much right?

Comment: I ended up writing a [tutorial](http://www.jaggedverge.com/2015/10/python-comprehension-syntax-for-java-developers/) about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is this list comprehension in Python?

First let’s start with the basic definition taken from the official Python documentation.

A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression followed by a `for` clause, then zero or more `for` or `if` clauses. The result will be a new list resulting from evaluating the expression in the context of the `for` and `if` clauses which follow it.

> The problem is it's everywhere, nearly all the examples I found here and there use it.

List comprehension is a very flexible concept. It allows us to define lists as we know from the mathematics. Say we have a set `S` in which each element of `S` is a square of a number `x` and `x` could only takes values ranging from `0` to `10`.

See the above definition. It took a paragraph to describe it. But there is a better way to describe it.

```
S = {x² : x in {0 ... 10}}
```

That’s why I love math, it is always to the point. Now remember your first example?

```
S = [x**2 for x in range(10)]
```

That’s the set we just defined. Neat right? That’s why it is used so much. (Don’t get confused with the `x**2` syntax, because Python follows a weird syntax here which you probably might be familiar as `x^2` from other languages.)

In Python you can iterate over pretty much anything. Which basically means you can easily iterate over each character of a string. Let’s look at the second example. It just iterates over the words `‘abc’` and `‘def’` and creates a list out of them.

```
lst = [j + k for j in 'abc' for k in 'def']
```

Notice that we assigned this to a list named `lst`. It was no coincidence. **Python is the most humane programming language I have ever laid eyes on.** So she will help you when you get stuck. Like this.

```
help(lst)
```

You can now see what you can do with `lst`. Ever got confused what `lst` is? You can check what it is via `type`.

```
print type(lst)
```

Before we move forward let’s talk a little bit about **iterators** and **generators**.

Iterators are objects that you can call `next()` method on. Like this.

```
iterator = iter([1,2,3,4])
```

Now we can print the first element of our iterator, like this.

```
print iterator.next()
```

Now we can talk about the generators. They are functions that generate iterators. There is however one other concept called **generator expressions**.

```
(x for x in (0,1,2,3,4))
```

This is a generator expression. A generator expressions is like a shortcut to build generators out of expressions similar to that of list comprehensions.

```
total = sum(x+y for x in (0,1,2,3) for y in (0,1,2,3) if x < y)
```

What above line does is to first create a generator using a generator expression and iterate over each element and sum those elements.

Comment: OMG. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also note that the "weird syntax" Python uses here is because of `^` being a bitwise operator. In fact, it is such in many languages. `**` is just a convenient operator for `math.pow(x, y)`.

Comment: Thanks for noting that, this is definetly a good remark for future references to this question.

Comment: I was actually trying to look into what other languages do here. I know C/C++/Java don't have an operator at all, only a function equivalent to Python's `pow`. [Some languages](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Exponentiation_operator) apparently provide `^^` (same reason; to distinguish bitwise `^`) and only BASIC seems to exponentiate with `^`.

Comment: Wow, I thought it was more common, but if that's the case, I think I should remove that statement. I don't want to mislead anyone :)